# Complex type of JSON to load in Object in Type Script

Tags: json, typescript

I have a complex type of JSON which I want to load in my model in typescript. The problem is I am receiving this JSON from a third party and they are sending data as object instead of array. Is there any way to load data into a model?

```
{
   "members":{
      "8392883213":{
         "requestingCoverageIndicator":true,
         "demographic":{
            "ssn":"999888888",
            "birthDate":"1980-01-01",
            "name":{
               "firstName":"Susan",
               "middleName":"Carrie",
               "lastName":"Griffith",
               "suffix":"Jr."
            }
         }
      },
      "8392883222":{
         "requestingCoverageIndicator":true,
         "demographic":{
            "ssn":"999888888",
            "birthDate":"1980-01-01",
            "name":{
               "firstName":"Susan",
               "middleName":"Carrie",
               "lastName":"Griffith",
               "suffix":"Jr."
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you have to iterate this object and need to create `members` array according to the needs of yourself.

Comment: Please provide more detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```js
const bla = {
   "members":{
      "8392883213":{
         "requestingCoverageIndicator":true,
         "demographic":{
            "ssn":"999888888",
            "birthDate":"1980-01-01",
            "name":{
               "firstName":"Susan",
               "middleName":"Carrie",
               "lastName":"Griffith",
               "suffix":"Jr."
            }
         }
      },
      "8392883222":{
         "requestingCoverageIndicator":true,
         "demographic":{
            "ssn":"999888888",
            "birthDate":"1980-01-01",
            "name":{
               "firstName":"Susan",
               "middleName":"Carrie",
               "lastName":"Griffith",
               "suffix":"Jr."
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
console.log(Object.keys(bla.members).map(ele => bla.members[ele]));
```

Comment: `Object.values(bla.members)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
interface Members {
    [key: string]: Indicator;
}

interface Indicator {
    requestingCoverageIndicator: boolean;
    demographic: Demographic;
}

interface Demographic {
    ssn: string;
    birthDate: string;
    name: Name;
}

interface Name {
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
    lastName: string;
    suffix: string;
}
```